# how would I add variable: var name=prompt("") into html

Tags: javascript, html

how would I add variable: **var name=prompt("Give us your email to sign up to our newsletter");**  into html, to send a copy of my websites newsletter to them?

I am pretty new to javascript so there may be an obvious answer, but I have searched far and wide and haven't gotten the answer i need.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Magneto;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: #ddfdff;
}

form {
  font-family: Magneto;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #ddfdff;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/d/7/4/341499-free-wallpaper-4k-3840x2160-for-computer.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Website Name</h1>
    <center>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <img src="https://www.encompasscorporation.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/white-arrow-down.png" width="100" height="100">
      <h1>Sign up to our newsletter</h1>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        Full Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
        <br> Email
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </center>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Within script tags?

Comment: you would need a lot more than that variable in the HTML to accomplish sending out newsletters.....

Comment: do you have any idea how I might accomplish that?

Comment: To actually be able to send newsletter, you could use PHP. I suggest you to use jQuery. To put it in steps: 1) Prompt the user for email 2) Send this email to PHP file via AJAX 3) Process it in PHP and send newsletter

Comment: Well somehow you also need to submit it back to your server so you know to save it.... Seems like a sign up form would be a lot better than a prompt. And what about people who get it,  are they going to get the promptevery time they go to the page?

Comment: that is a problem...so if I set up a form, were might I send the E-mail after. PHP or...

Comment: If you have a form, the form method could be a PHP file which handles the form data and sends emails

Comment: I have added a form that would go to a PHP file were I can send my newsletter. Thank you all for your help, I know what do do from here.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and parts are even obsolete.

Comment: I plan to clean up and debug my code after I have finished my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how to get the e-mail address ONLY.

I don't recommend using the prompt though, it doesn't look nice.  I'd create a prompt instead that looks better - https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You'll still have a lot of steps like:
  1.  Getting the data to the server
  2.  Getting it into a database
  3.  Creating a process to read that database and send info.

```
var name=prompt("Give us your email to sign up to our newsletter")


h1{
  font-family: Magneto;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: white;
}

body{
  background-image: url("https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/d/7/4/341499-free-wallpaper-4k-3840x2160-for-computer.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>website</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Website Name</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name=prompt("Give us your email to sign up to our newsletter")
</script>
```

Comment: This HTML is invalid and parts are even obsolete.